# What's this "Chat with an expert" popup thing?

Tags: support, chat

I got a couple of mini popups asking if I want to "Chat with an expert" (once on SFF, twice on Politics).

Is this some new functionality of SE sites? Or a trojan I picked up somewhere?

Comment: Disappointing! I am an Iranian and got the matter but didn't you?! :)(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did it occur to you to check the date that this "expert chat" appeared?  (Hint: Today is the first day of April.)  I chatted with one and it's a bot - apparently based on an Eliza type program.

Comment: Um. No, till i read this, I didn't realize today is 4/1 :(   Fair'nuff guess

Comment: Also, you are CLEARLY not paranoid enough as far as internet security, if you feel free to chat with randomly appearing bots (or any popups) of unknown origin. My first instinct is to shut them down till I know they are safe.

Comment: @DVK I immediately worried that I'd gotten some malware, so googled "Chat with an expert".  [This was the third hit I got](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174407/166646).  You can never be too paranoid!

Comment: @Beofett - Quoting from a meta comment: "Yes, always click on random unexpected links in pop-up messages on websites where you don't expect. What harm can come from that? – JonW" . In all seriousness, until I read Tango's reply I had no idea it was 4/1

Comment: Is there anyway to disable it? Or should I just avoid SE for the rest of the day?

Comment: @JimGreen You can click the 'never' link in the popup banner.  I found that wasn't working for me across all SE sites though, so I posted [how to disable it via your browser's CSS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174596/158781) over on Meta.SO.